# Is there a performance hit in ios development using If statements?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to debug my games code. I'm developing a game for iOS and my code uses a lot of IF statements. I would like to know if there is even a very small performance hit when using these.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is a performance hit when branching.

But you can't make a reasonable program without branch.

So use the `if`, and if by profiling your program you detect a problem on a specific location in your code, try to see if you can reduce the numbers of branchings or to put them out of the loops. But don't pay too much attention to it as long as the code remains clear.

Most of the time, the first impact of numerous `if` is on readability and maintainability. But premature optimization is often a greater hit on those topics.

Comment: and almost always, it is not the branching itself that is heavy, but evaluating the conditions. Thinking about their order and repetitiveness could help (caveat about premature optimization applies).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you used your if statements, there are some performance regarding using if in the right way

I will state some of them

- Always use the if that is most likely to happen before the else, use the cases that are more common before then use the ones that are less likely
- try to use if before the loops,
  For example

instead of this

```
BOOL isCase1 = [self isCase1];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i ++)
{
   if(isCase1)
   {
       //do something
   }
   else
   {
      //do some other thing
   }
}
```

use this

```
   BOOL isCase1 = [self isCase1];

   if(isCase1)
   {
       for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i ++)
       {
       }
   }
   else
   {
       for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i ++)
       {
       }
   }
```

Dont assume that you will need to improve performance before you are sure, most of the time your performance is doing good, if you are sure that some code is causing performance issues improve it (dont premature optimize your code)

These are some of the cases, there are much more

**UPDATE:**

Some other helpful things you could do, cache your boolean checking statments

for example

Instead of

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i ++)
{
   if([self isCase1]) //Do some thing
}
```

use

```
//Cache the result inside a variable
BOOL isCase = [self isCase1];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i ++)
{
   if(isCase) //Do some thing
}
```

Comment: +1 for the example of pulling stuff out of loops (applies to all kinds of other things as well, not just if statements).

Comment: Note that a decent compiler will already perform this optimisation, so check first otherwise you just obfuscate your code for nothing.

Comment: @PaulR if you are sure that the compiler can do that, please post some references, also i already stated above about not to do this until 100% sure that the code has a performance issue :)

Comment: @Omar: I used to use this as a teaching example for an optimisation class but had to drop it in recent years because (a) gcc and other compilers now take care of this kind of transformation and (b) branch prediction in modern CPUs has improved to the point where it's often of no benefit even when the compiler doesn't do the transformation. 10 years ago this was a very useful optimisation, technology doesn't stand still for very long.

Comment: @PaulR i agree with you 100% most optimization should not be done, code should be readable by human before even thinking about performance, but in some specific cases, that when profiling the profiler points to a segment of code, and that code contains something similar to what i wrote above, then its useful to know that you may change it manually

Comment: @Omar: yes - agreed - I wasn't actually criticising your answer, just pointing out that, like a lot of things, what was useful once may now have been rendered obsolete (or even counter-productve) by improvements in compilers and CPU architecture.